# How to convert ‘std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<2629746l, 1l> >’ to ‘int’ type?

Tags: c++, date, c++11, c++-chrono, static-cast

I am using [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), and trying to find the total number of months between two dates.

> ```
> invalid static_cast from type ‘std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<2629746l, 1l> >’ to type ‘int’
>   int period = static_cast<int>(period_in_months(start_date, end_date));
> ```

Here are the functions I am using:

```
auto period_in_months(year_month_day start_date, year_month_day end_time) {
   auto total_months = ((end_time.year() - start_date.year())*12 + (end_time.month() - start_date.month()));
   return (total_months--);
}

double percentage_return(string risk_profile, year_month_day start_date, year_month_day end_date) {
   int period = static_cast<int>(period_in_months(start_date, end_date));
   // do something 
}
```

I tried using `chrono::duration_cast<int>(period_in_months(start_date, end_date)` but received the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an article on this subject:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#deltamonths

The article starts with more questions:

> Do we want the number of "full months"? Or perhaps we should round to
>   the nearest number of integral months? Or do we want a floating-point
>   representation of months which can show fractional months?

Given two `year_month_day` objects `d1` and `d2`, here is the difference in months truncated towards zero:

```
(d2.year()/d2.month() - d1.year()/d1.month())
```

This returns a `chrono` duration called `months`.

The above completely ignores the day field of each date.  If you want to take the day field into account and round towards nearest:

```
auto dp1 = sys_days(d1);
auto dp2 = sys_days(d2);
auto delta = round<months>(dp2-dp1);
```

There's also a way to get the difference in floating point months shown in the article.

Once you have a `chrono` duration of any precision, with any representation, one can get the value of that representation out with the `.count()` member function of `chrono::duration`:

```
cout << delta.count() << '\n';
```

Comment: And, how can we convert `delta` to int ?

Comment: @Shravan40:  If it helps, here is a video tutorial just on chrono: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  Good to know as the date library builds on chrono.

Comment: It's always feel special when your question get answered by library author.

Answer (score 4):

Instances of `std::chrono::duration` template are not (even explicitly) convertible to `int`. A cast won't work. If you take a look at [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), you'll find that there is no conversion operator.

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) of `std::chrono::duration_cast` you'll find that

> The function does not participate in the overload resolution unless ToDuration is an instance of std::chrono::duration.

`int` is not an instance of `std::chrono::duration`, so your second attempt won't work.

---

If you take a look at the reference of `std::chrono::duration` again, you'll find the `count` member function, which

> Returns the number of ticks for this duration.

This is what you're looking for. First use `chrono::duration_cast` to convert the duration to a form that represents the time as an integer with appropriate tick duration (a month in this case), then call `count` on that duration representation. The duration cast step is unnecessary if your duration is already in the desired representation.